# SQLAlchemy Django: How can I import external Table declarations into the same Metadata?

Tags: django, sqlalchemy

I am using Django in combination with SQLAlchemy. I have the problem of putting all the Table declarations into the same Metadata.
I have several modules in different packages with table declarations using the declarative method, some tables have relationships. 
When I run the `create_all` command I got errors because the referred Tables in different packages are not present in the Metadata.

More exactly this is the line of code in SQLAlchemy that performs that validation:

```
if _get_table_key(tname, schema) not in parenttable.metadata:
    raise exc.NoReferencedTableError(
        "Foreign key associated with column '%s' could not find "
        "table '%s.%s' with which to generate a "
        "foreign key to target column '%s'" % (schema, self.parent, tname, colname),
                tname)
        table = Table(tname, parenttable.metadata,
                      mustexist=True, schema=schema)
```

I am lost with this, I have already read the documentation and several post but I didnt find the answer.

Is there any way to attach the external table modules to an existing Metadata?

Thanks.